# Java NoSuchMethodException when getting constructor

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to use reflections to load an instance of a class. I am getting a no such method exception when I try and do it. I have checked and checked and re-checked. That constructor clearly does exist. Does anyone have any ideas? I have successfully used this before on another project with essentially identical code so I'm not sure where I screwed up. Source can be found here:

```
private void loadCommands() {
        try {
            for (Class<?> clazz : ReflectionsReplacement.getSubtypesOf(BaseCommand.class, "us.zsugano.itemsave.commands", plugin.getClass().getClassLoader(), BaseCommand.class)) {

                BaseCommand baseCommand = null;
                try {
                    baseCommand = (BaseCommand) clazz.getConstructor(ItemSave.class).newInstance(plugin);

                    if(Listener.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents((Listener) baseCommand, plugin);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    plugin.PluginPM.sendMessage(Level.SEVERE, "Issues encountered when trying to load commands.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                commands.add(baseCommand);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            plugin.PluginPM.sendMessage(Level.SEVERE, "Exception caught while loading commands.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (BaseCommand command : commands) {
            plugin.getCommand(command.getName().toLowerCase()).setExecutor(this);
        }

}

public abstract class BaseCommand {

    public ItemSave plugin;

    public BaseCommand(ItemSave plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
}
```

Full Source: https://github.com/zachoooo/ItemSave

And here is the Stack Trace:

```
19:43:10 [SEVERE] [ItemSave] Issues encountered when trying to load commands.
19:43:10 [SEVERE] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: us.zsugano.itemsave.commands.
StoreCommand.<init>(us.zsugano.itemsave.ItemSave)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at us.zsugano.itemsave.commands.CommandManager.loadComma
nds(CommandManager.java:32)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at us.zsugano.itemsave.commands.CommandManager.<init>(Co
mmandManager.java:23)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at us.zsugano.itemsave.ItemSave.onEnable(ItemSave.java:1
9)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlug
in.java:217)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(
JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(Si
mplePluginManager.java:381)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin
(CraftServer.java:282)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.enablePlug
ins(CraftServer.java:264)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.l(Minecr
aftServer.java:313)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.f(Minecr
aftServer.java:290)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.a(Minecr
aftServer.java:250)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.init(Ded
icatedServer.java:151)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(Mine
craftServer.java:391)
19:43:10 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.
run(SourceFile:582)
```

Comment: Just wild idea, but maybe try `getDeclaredConstructor` instead of `getConstructor` in case constructor is not public. Also you shouldn't link source code but add it to question.

Comment: It is definitely public, and I didn't want to have to include the source for a couple files on the page, that would make my question rather long. Should I do it anyways?

Comment: No, you should trim it down to a full program containing only a few lines of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You should post only essential parts of code. That shouldn't be too long.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to go through the process of trying to replicate this with just two classes.  You may learn more about the problem, and failing that you'll have code to post that clearly demonstrates the problem with minimal distraction (to us) of all the rest of the things you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've done it before, it is possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In StoreCommand.java I see this package private constructor:

```
StoreCommand(ItemSave plugin) {
  super(plugin);
}
```

from the API docs of getConstructor (emphasis mine):

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified **public**
>   constructor of the class represented by this Class object.

Either make the constructor public or use `getDeclaredConstructor()` and set then do `setAccesible(true)`

Comment: Oh, did not realize I had to make all subclasses public as well

Comment: @Gus: works when we add no-arg constructor in addition to the parameterized-constructor.